# spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-file delete the file after processing

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to utilize spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-file app (https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/file/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-file) to poll a directory and send the file ref to custom processor for further processing.

Is there an option available to delete the file after being processed by the source app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have the option to delete the processed file for the [`file-source`](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/file) yet. Feel free to add a story in the [file-source backlog](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/file/issues/2) - we welcome contributions, too!

As an alternative, you could use the [`sftp-source`](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/sftp/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-sftp/README.adoc), and that includes an option to delete the remote files on successful ingest.